# Angular 8 button disable based on form invalid

Tags: angular

I am  new to Angular and I am working in 8.

I tried the following to disable a submit button. I have one parent component request.html, here I am using the following code,

```
<div i"parent">
<form #heroForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="vname" name="name" #name="ngModel" #spy>

    <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger"> Name is required </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid || spy.className.invalid">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

It disbales the submit button as expected, if textbox is empty. This is not a problem

Now I am using other child component inject in request.html, as follows

```
<form #heroForm="ngForm">
    <div id="parent">
        <app-child>  </app-child>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
      [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid || spy.className.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and my child html looks like follows,

```
<div id="child-template">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="vname" name="name" #name="ngModel" #spy>

    <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger"> Name is required </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here My input text box is in child html and I want to disable the save button in parent html, it is not working and the save button always enabled.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Can you add your child ts file?

Comment: yes, everything added while generate using CLI

Comment: Show your child ts code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can find** out complete working [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsapi6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

You have to emit form status form child to parent using `@Output()` and `@ViewChild()` decorator.
Your app.component.html is... `submitValidator` is just coming from child component.

```
<div id="parent">
    <app-child (submitValidator)="onSubmitValidator($event)">  </app-child>
</div>
```

**Your child.component.ts is ...**

- here, @ViewChild() is used for getting form status from template, where you have used `#name=ngModel`

  ```
  @Output() submitValidator = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild ('name', {static:false}) formValidator;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.submitValidator.emit(false);
  }
  onChange(value){
      this.submitValidator.emit(this.formValidator.valid)
  }
  ```

**Your chil.component.html is...**

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onChange()" 
        id="name" required [(ngModel)]="vname" name="name" 
        #name="ngModel" #spy
 >
```

Comment: thanks, for me button is disable. Even after providing input, after 5 chars only error message hide and button disabled.

Comment: not understand properly of what you are trying to say about problem? and have you checked stackblitz link above?

Comment: I updated the stackblitz  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsapi6?embed=1&file=src/app/child/child.component.html

Comment: I am dynamically generating the elements using ngFor, during this time when one of the input has value it enables the button. Can you please help in this?

Comment: can you please provide the URL, its showing only my last changes

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsapi6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204166/discussion-between-devgo-and-gaurangdhorda).

Answer (score 1):

Use @Output decorator, which will emit an event to enable/ disable button from child to parent.
The event can be called on ngModelChange event of input text box.